# How to convert a scalar dense layer output into a matrix with each element being equal to the scalar in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

How to convert a scalar dense layer output of shape `(none,1)` into a matrix of shape `(none,nx,ny,nc)` with each element of the matrix being equal to the scalar in TensorFlow 2.0 using Keras?

Code snippet:

```
Y= tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu')(X)
Z= Y*tf.keras.backend.ones(shape=(10,51,1))
```

Here Y is of shape `(none,1)`. I want Z to be of shape `(none,10,51,1)` but I am getting a shape of `(10,51,1)`. Somehow the batch size dimension `(none)` is lost when I multiply. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
Y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu')(X)
Z = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda y:
    tf.keras.backend.tile(y[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], (1, 10, 51, 1))(Y)
```